# jQuery: Wrap outputted text in span?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery script that inserts an `<input>` after the outputted text. My question is how do I wrap the outputted text in a `<span>` before the `<input>` is called?

```
$(".todo-deadline").each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).text() + "<input readonly='readonly' class='hasDatepicke2' type='text' value='"+$(this).text()+"' />");
});
```

Comment: what is the desired output

Comment: <span>OUTPUTTED TEXT</span><input>OUTPUTTED TEXT</input>

Comment: Have you tried just adding a '<span>' and '</span>, around $(this).text() just like how the input is being added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$(".todo-deadline").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this), text = $this.text();
    $this.empty().append($('<span />', {
        text: text
    })).append('<input readonly="readonly" class="hasDatepicke2" type="text" value="' + text + '" />')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LFQMU/)

Or

```
$(".todo-deadline").html(function(idx, html) {
    return '<span>' + html + '</span>' + '<input readonly="readonly" class="hasDatepicke2" type="text" value="' + html + '" />'
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LFQMU/2/)